# verify an email pgp signature in python

Tags: python, email, gnupg

I'm trying to verify the signature of an encrypted e-mail-message using python-gnupg. The follwing code decrypts the content and extracts the message and the signature.

```py
from email.policy import SMTP
from email.parser import BytesParser
from gnupg import GPG

gpg = GPG()

with open('04333.msg', 'rb') as fp:
    msg = BytesParser(policy=SMTP).parse(fp)
 
if msg.is_multipart():
    for part in msg.iter_parts():
        if (part.get_content_type()=='application/octet-stream'):
            content = part.get_content()
            message = gpg.decrypt(content)
            msg_in = BytesParser(policy=SMTP).parsebytes(message.data)
           
            #I tried: gpg.verify(message.data)
            #But it doesn't work
           
            for part_in in msg_in.iter_parts():
                content_type_in = part_in.get_content_type()
                if content_type_in == 'text/plain':
                    text = part_in.get_content()
                elif content_type_in == 'application/pgp-signature':
                    sig = part_in.get_content()

            print("text: ")
            print(text)
            print("sig: ")
            print(sig)
```

It gives me:

```
text: 
bar
sig: 
b'-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----\n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\n0zflhV3sxrvgARJEG8goLJWxH39A84rGQQa3rkYDR+HcFWqjzfg=\n=CpBa\n-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----\n'
```

Looks good, but how do I verify the signature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for OpenPGP\MIME and binary signature (sigclass 0x00):

```py
from email.policy import SMTP
from email.parser import BytesParser
from gnupg import GPG
from tempfile import mkstemp
import os
gpg = GPG()

with open('04333.msg', 'rb') as fp:
    msg = BytesParser(policy=SMTP).parse(fp)
 
if msg.is_multipart():
    for part in msg.iter_parts():
        if (part.get_content_type()=='application/octet-stream'):
            content = part.get_content()
            message = gpg.decrypt(content)
            msg_in = BytesParser(policy=SMTP).parsebytes(message.data)

            for part_in in msg_in.iter_parts():
                content_type_in = part_in.get_content_type()
                if content_type_in == 'text/plain':
                    text = part_in.get_content()
                    data = part_in.as_bytes()
                elif content_type_in == 'application/pgp-signature':
                    sig = part_in.get_content()
            
            import tempfile
            osfile, path = mkstemp()
            try:
                with os.fdopen(osfile, 'wb') as fd:
                    fd.write(sig)
                
                if (gpg.verify_data(path, data)):
                    print('signature validated!')
            finally:
                os.unlink(path)
```

It saves the signature into a temporary file. Then checks the signature with the raw data of the 'text/plain' message part.